# Way to use twiiter hashtags in python sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, twitter

Is there any way to extract twitter hashtags in this code instead of tweets from a single user. I am working on sentiment analysis in python/

```
# Extract 100 tweets from the twitter user
posts = api.user_timeline(screen_name="OlectraEbus", count = 100, lang ="en", tweet_mode="extended")

#  Print the last 5 tweets
print("Show the 5 recent tweets:\n")
i=1
for tweet in posts[:5]:
    print(str(i) +') '+ tweet.full_text + '\n')
    i= i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for my team was making a data frame. Each row represents a tweet and the columns include mentions, hashtags, time, date, etc. Since one of the columns is the "hashtag" column, containing the hashtags of each tweet, you can easily select tweets with specific hashtags using that column.